# Is there any usable MvxCollectionViewCell sample that reflects 5.x version of MvvmCross

Tags: mvvmcross

MvxCollectionViewCell samples that I can find on Internet are not reflecting current version of MvvmCross (5.x).
DelayBind does not exist as a method of binding.
Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, Visual Studio somehow created local MvxCollectionViewCell.cs so I inherited from empty class.
Please ignore my question.